# Access data in ASP without code behin

Tags: sqldatasource

I need to read some value from DB in ASP, I try this code and works fine:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource12" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conexion1 %>" 
SelectCommand="select Quantity from XW_ReqLine where ReqNbr=@reqnbr1">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter 
    ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" 
    DefaultValue="10124"
    Direction="Input" 
    Name="reqnbr1" 
    QueryStringField="string" 
    Type="String" />                                                                                               
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView15" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource12" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

I need to change DefaultValue=**"10124"** to DefaultValue="**<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReqNbr") %>**" but after that, IIS show an error. The change is because this parameter is not constant

Note: I can't access the code behind (is a comercial software) and only I can made this modifications in the ASP file.

Comment: What error is IIS giving you?

Comment: Have you tried `DefaultValue="<% =DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReqNbr") %>"`?

Comment: Hi user2366842, this is the error: [link](http://imageshack.us/a/img594/8796/55m0.png) thanks

Comment: Hi Chad, yes, I tried it but not work :(

Comment: This isn't a classic asp question, it;s .net